# How to use react-i18next in a utility function outside the component tree?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I followed the [react-i18next docs](https://react.i18next.com/) and internationalized my React app.

I use the `useTranslation` hook, which gives me the "t" object. All nice and smooth for now, but I have some non-Hook utility functions which are outside the component tree.

How to get access to the translation object there?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work, import `i18next` rather than `react-i18next`:

```
// import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import i18next from "i18next";
function hello() {
    return i18next.t("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This one worked for me,

//import i18next

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
```

//Then where ever you need to try like this

```
i18next.t('common:messages.errorMessage')
```

Comment: This worked for me, although I needed to change the i18n config by adding the "ns" and "defaultNs" properties.
Also, a common mistake is that the JSON file is "broken", meaning that you had a key-value pair where the value contains quotes, make sure you put "\" before each quote.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if it will work, but can you try this:

```
import i18n from "react-i18next";

// Then where ever you need try to this

i18n.t("target")
```

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg , what about to set i18n.t function to a Static property of Class or something, and then reach that i18n.t function statically from outside component